# Detach a child process from Casperjs

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to develop an test script with casperjs that, in case of failure of a single test, sends an email to the developer.

The mailing script is made with nodejs using nodemailer.
If the function that starts the mailer is somewhere in the casperjs script it works perfectly, the problem comes when the test fails: it seems that casperjs exists without leaving the time to the child process to complete.

The only way I found to make it work is to add a --auto-exit=no and to explicitly exit when I receive the mailer response. But I'd like to avoid passing the param outside the script.

Is there a way to:
set inside the script the auto-exit option?
OR to detach the child process so that it doesn't die when the parent exits?

Listener:

```
casper.test.on("fail", function(failure){
      casper.capture(image_dir+'/ERROR.png');
        tools.sendMail(
        tools.config.recipients,
        'Errore '+tools.config.website,
        'Il Test sul controllo login è fallito. In allegato screenshot del problema.',
        'Il Test sul controllo login è fallito. In allegato screenshot del problema.',
        'screenshots/login'+'/ERROR.png'
    );  

});
```

Function

```
var sendMail = function($to,$subject,$text,$html,$attachments) {
    var childProcess;

    try {
        childProcess = require("child_process");
    } catch (e) {
        casper.echo("error"+e);
    }
    if (childProcess) {
        childProcess.execFile("/usr/bin/nodejs", ["common/mailer.js", $to, $subject, $text, $html , $attachments], null, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
            casper.echo("----------------------execFileSTDOUT:"+ JSON.stringify(stdout));
            casper.echo("----------------------execFileSTDERR:"+ JSON.stringify(stderr));
            casper.exit(1);
        });
        casper.echo("Done");
    } else {
        casper.echo("Unable to require child process");
    }
};
```

I've also tried to use "nohup /usr/bin/nodejs" but with no luck.

Thanks

Comment: I somehow doubt that there is a more elegant way than what was shown in the documentation about `--auto-exit`. Btw, nohup needs an ampersand at the end of the command to detach properly. Have you tried that? `childProcess.execFile("/usr/bin/nodejs", ["common/mailer.js", $to, $subject, $text, $html , $attachments, "&"] ...`

Comment: Thank you for the reply,
yes, I've tried but it doesn't work. I think because it puts the params  within quotes. 
I'll try to create the complete command in one string and pass it as the first param of execFile, leaving the others blank.